# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos que no se cruzaron con el comando merge?

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy utilizando el comando merge en Rstudio para cruzar dos bases, pero necesito extraer los datos que no se cruzaron.¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Comment: Hola Francisco, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece a "tengo este ejercicio, háganlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de

Comment: Como estás haciendo el merge? puedes copiar la llamada a tu pregunta?